Show that if $G$ is a Lie group with a bi-invariant metric, the left- and right-invariant vector fields of $G$ are Killing fields.
How do I show that if $G$ is a Lie group with a bi-invariant metric, the left- and right-invariant vector fields of $G$ are Killing fields?
Here is my attempt. If $X$ is a left- or right-invariant vector field, I want to show that $\mathcal L_Xg = 0$. For that, let $Y$, and $Z$ be arbitrary vector fields. Then
$$(\mathcal L_X g)(Y,Z) = X(g(Y,Z)) - g([X,Y],Z) - g(Y,[X,Z]).$$
Because $g$ is bi-invariant, it is also $\mathrm{ad}$-invariant, so the last two terms on the RHS cancel. This leaves me with:
$$(\mathcal L_X g)(Y,Z) = X(g(Y,Z)).$$
Why is this zero for $X$ left- or right-invariant?

The part where you said $g([X,Y],Z) + g(Y, [X,Z]) = 0$ only holds if $Y$ and $Z$ are also left (or right)-invariant vector fields, right? In that case, because the metric is invariant, $g(Y,Z)$ is constant. I think for general vector fields $Y$ and $Z$, you can (pointwise) express them as the linear combination of left (or right)-invariant vector fields and conclude from there.

This follows from the facts that a left invariant vector field is the derivative of a parametrized family of left translations and left translations are isometries.

I think Deane might have swapped things around? The flow of a left-invariant field consists of right-translations, and vice versa. This means that if the metric $g$ is left-invariant, then right-invariant fields are Killing fields.
